# JQuery expands all divs on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One div works fine, however when using multiple divs they all get expanded simultaneously.

Here 1x
http://jsfiddle.net/uPzXh/1/

Here 2x
http://jsfiddle.net/uPzXh/

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? It's working as it should...

Comment: Please provide more detail about your problem.

Comment: The divs should be expanded seperaly

Comment: Separately as in one click expands one `div`, or as in one click expands both, one after the other?

Comment: Please don't merely link to your code. Include it in the question so that if the links die or are temporarily unavailable, future readers can still benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".lol").hide();
   jQuery(".lollink").click(function() {
      jQuery(this).prev().slideToggle(500);
      jQuery(this,".new").hide();
  });
});
```

BTW `div` in `a` is not allowed according to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you have a div with the same class name twice. So this line of code:

```
jQuery(".lol").slideToggle(500);
```

is doing what you tell it to do .. open all elements with a class name of lol. 
Changing the class of the second div to lol2 would fix this.

Comment: Misses the point. The elements appear to be laid out similarly, and therefore having the same class makes sense.

Comment: @MichealMior How about you don't down-vote when I answered the question correctly. He asked why both divs were expanding and I explained it. Sorry i wasn't able to ascertain your grand understanding of the question.

Comment: @MichealMior Given all your deep understanding I dont see why you havent offered an answer... ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `$(this)` inside the click function rather than `$('.lol')`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uPzXh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to expand one `div` when one link is clicked (not expand both, one after the other). If that's right, you can do something like this:

```
jQuery(".lollink").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).hide().parent().find(".lol").slideToggle(500);
});
```

This hides the clicked element, gets the parent element, finds the descendant of that element with class `.lol` and toggles the slide on that.

See an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uPzXh/9/).